# Rails conditional validation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app where I'm trying to do some conditional validation on a model.

In the call model there are two fields :location_id (which is an association to a list of pre-defined locations) and :location_other (which is a text field where someone could type in a string or in this case an address).

What I want to be able to do is use validations when creating a call to where either the :location_id or :location_other is validated to be present.

I've read through the Rails validations guide and am a little confused.  Was hoping someone could shed some light on how to do this easily with a conditional.

Comment: I don't quite understand the core question. Is it about how to use the `if` and `unless` options of the valdates macros? Or is it about how to only validate on certain model attributes when saving a model from some controller actions (and not others)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I'm trying to figure out how to use if and unless when creating/saving a record.  The end goal is to verify that either the :location_id or :location_other is set when creating/saving  a record.  I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :location_id_or_other

  def location_id_or_other
    if location_id.blank? && location_other.blank?
      errors.add(:location_other, 'needs to be present if location_id is not present')
    end
  end
end
```

`location_id_or_other` is a custom validation method that checks if `location_id` and `location_other` are blank. If they both are, then it adds a validation error. If the presence of `location_id` and `location_other` is an **exclusive or**, i.e. only one of the two can be present, not either, and not both, then you can make the following change to the `if` block in the method.

```
if location_id.blank? == location_other.blank?
  errors.add(:location_other, "must be present if location_id isn't, but can't be present if location_id is")
end
```

**Alternate Solution**

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :location_id, presence: true, unless: :location_other
  validates :location_other, presence: true, unless: :location_id
end
```

This solution (only) works if the presence of `location_id` and `location_other` is an exclusive or.

Check out the [Rails Validation Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The first solution, creating a custom validation did the trick.  I was just doing some research on custom validations and started to write something similar, thanks for saving me time and teaching me.  I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! And check out the [Rails Validation Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) (which I also linked in my updated answer) for more info about validations.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I've been reading and was going off of when I started writing something similar.  But thanks again for stepping in so fast and coming up with a simple answer.  Much appreciated.