# Conditional validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model. In some cases I need to validate all its fields for presence and another kinds of stuff, in other cases I need to validate only some of them and other  fields can remain empty. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails conditional validation in model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641143/rails-conditional-validation-in-model)

Answer (score 5):

Check this

```
validates_presence_of :state, :if => :in_us?

def in_us?
  country == 'US'
end
```

Here it validates presence of state only if country is US. For other country id dosen't validates state.

For detail: http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

Answer (score -2):

You could use conditional validation.Please refer the doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#5.1