# Validate for params for separate forms for 1 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have an issue with a model. I have a model that is updated through 2 forms (as 2 people need to enter separate data). Form 1 contains the first half of the required data and therefor only that data needs to be validated there.

I am having trouble finding a way to validate only the data entered in form 1. Below you'll find my subscription.rb model file.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  # werkgever form

  if form_id == 'form1'
    validates :email, presence: true
  end

  # werknemer form
  if form_id == 'form2'
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :city presence: true
  end
end
```

I need the if statements to contain something that would make it so that only the values beloging to that form are validated so that i dont get errors on form2 when updating and vice versa.

I hope this is clear enough. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you distinguish for 1 and form 2? I think having them separated into different forms with a "form object" (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects) would be most ideal in this situation.

Comment: Here is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641143/rails-conditional-validation-in-model  Feel free to add virtual attribute to your model and pass it as hidden field via form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set validations with condition:

```
attr_accessor :form_type    

validates :email, presence: true, :if => :werkgever_form?

def werkgever_form?
  form_type == 'werkgever'
end
```

:form_type is a virtual attribute, which is not saved in the database and needed only for validations. You can set this attribute as a hidden field in each form:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :form_type, 'werkgever' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
attr_accessor :form_type
validates :email, presence: true, if: :check_if_form_one
validates :name, presence: true, unless: :check_if_form_one
validates :city presence: true, unless: :check_if_form_one

def check_if_form_one
  /* Add your condition here
    example: form_type == 'form1' */
end
```

You can set form_type from controller method or view page.